# How can I get Browser.text.include? to search for a variable? ( using Watir and Ruby )

Tags: ruby, variables, text, find, watir

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to find how to get the Bowser.text.include? to look for the value of textinclude that I give it earlier in the program.

It seems to search literally for #{textinclude}, which is obviously not present.

This is my current code:

---

```
print( 'Enter your website: ' ) 

website = gets() 

puts( "Testing #{website}" )

print( 'What text do you want to find? ' ) 

textinclude = gets()

puts( "Finding #{textinclude}" )

require 'watir'

browser = Watir::IE.new

browser.goto (website)

if browser.text.include? " #{textinclude} "

print("#{textinclude} present")   

else

print("text not present")

end
```

---

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that your exact code as pasted from your program?

Check the spaces around `if browser.text.include? " #{textinclude} "` and make sure those aren't interfering.  E.g. if the sentence you're looking for actually ends with a `fullstop` rather than a `space` it could cause the `include?` to return false in my experience.

You will require the .chomp like Tapio Saarinen said, otherwise you will get `\n` at the end of your `textinclude variable`, removing this is the first step to being able to find your text.

So I would try this

```
text_include = gets.chomp
if browser.text.include?(text_include)
puts "Found it"
else 
puts "Didnt find it"
end
```

If that still fails, think about where the text is on the page.  If it's in a button's value, or somewhere that is otherwise not actually `text` on the page, then the `text.include?` will not find it at all.

P.s. I renamed your variable so I could read it properly :)

Comment: I've tested this with the website www.google.com and searching for the words "A faster", which appear on the top right of my google homepage and it's working for me, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if browser.text.include?(textinclude)
```

instead of

```
if browser.text.include? " #{textinclude} "
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding .chomp after gets() to remove the newline character(s) in the string to be searched for

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work either. Do we know if it is possible to pull a variable into the browser.text.include? command?